# How to solve this error its a telegram bot using pyrogram library

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

pyrogram.dispatcher - dispatcher - ERROR - 'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker

```
await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
```

File "/app/plugins/pm_filter.py", line 53, in give_filter

```
await client.delete_messages(message.chat.id, st_msg.message_id)
```

AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'message_id'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O17M.jpg)

Why showing this? How to fix this

Comment: you need to look which fields does Message class have. May be it just id not message_id

Answer (score 0):

##### **tl;dr**;

Use `st_msg.id` instead off `st_msg.message_id`

---

If you look at the [`reply_sticker` source code](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/efac17198b5fcaec1c2628c4bba0c288a4d617d4/pyrogram/types/messages_and_media/message.py#L2160) it mentions:

> Returns:
>
> On success, the sent :`obj:~pyrogram.types.Message` is returned.
> ...

So if we look at those `Message` parameters, for example, again [in the source code](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/blob/efac17198b5fcaec1c2628c4bba0c288a4d617d4/pyrogram/types/messages_and_media/message.py) we'll see:

> id (`int`):
> Unique message identifier inside this chat.

Answer (score 0):

`message_id` attribute is only supported in Pyrogram versions below 2.0

Consider using the latest version or try to downgrade